# Unable to view stats for READ and Wrong stats for WRITE and ALL with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have questions regarding the graph below for Cosmos DB throughput:

[image: ure]
Q1
How to view statistics for READ, not write? I cannot select for READ.

Q2:
The graph above shows ALL, or Write, whose statistics are exactly the same. Why do ALL and WRITE have the same graph?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a single region account. In a single region account with [Multi Master](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#configure-multiple-write-regions) not enabled, one region acts as the Write region (where your write requests go), and other regions act as Read replicas.

The dropdown you show has 2 subsections, Write (for Write regions) and Read (for Read regions), since you only have one region, you see no items within Read and your "All" selection will always match the single Write region.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain some additional details with diagnostic logging which you can look into here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging

You can also do somethings through the CosmosDB SDK:

https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/01/cosmos-db-query-execution-metrics.html

Since CosmosDB does not charge based on writes but instead based upon "request units" so I don't believe they provide a specific metric for inserts.